# 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning

I have error `'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'` while run my program. When I checked the problem seems because of i try to train my machine learning using list as my input.

**This is my list**:

```
list train:
[array([ 1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1.,  1.,  1., -1.,
        1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.,  1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,
       -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1.,  1.,  1., -1.,
        1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.,  1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,
       -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1.,  1.,  1., -1.,
        1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.,  1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,
       -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1.,  1.,  1., -1.,
        1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.,  1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,
       -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1.,  1.,  1., -1.,
        1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.,  1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,
       -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])]
```

**This is my program:**

```
X, y = load_svmlight_file(filedir)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.8, random_state=0)
print 'X_test',X_test

#my machine learning
clf1=Pa1()
clf2=Ogd()
clf3=Rda()

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=False, random_state=0) 
lst_train_pred1 = []
lst_test_pred1 =[]
lst_train_pred2 = []
lst_test_pred2 =[]
   
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X_train, y_train): 
    x_train_fold, x_test_fold = X_train[train_index], X_train[test_index] 
    y_train_fold, y_test_fold = y_train[train_index], y_train[test_index] 
    clf1.fit(x_train_fold, y_train_fold)
    clf2.fit(x_train_fold, y_train_fold)
    #1
    testpred1 = clf1.predict(X_test)
    trainpred1 = clf1.predict(x_test_fold)
    lst_train_pred1.append(trainpred)
    lst_test_pred1.append(testpred)
    #2
    testpred2 = clf2.predict(X_test)
    trainpred2 = clf2.predict(x_test_fold)
    lst_train_pred2.append(trainpred)
    lst_test_pred2.append(testpred)

list_train = lst_train_pred1+lst_train_pred2
print 'list train:\n',list_train
print '\n'
list_test = lst_test_pred1+lst_test_pred2
print 'list test:\n',list_test

finalpred = clf3.fit(list_train, y_train)
finaltest = clf3.predict(list_test, y_test)
```

**traceback error**

```
ttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-143-67930a24a60a> in <module>()
     59 print 'list test\n',list_test
     60 
---> 61 finalpred = clf3.fit(list_train, y_train)
     62 finaltest = clf3.predict(list_test, y_test)

/home/nida/pylibol/python/classifiers_data.pyc in fit(self, X, Y)
    373                 except AttributeError as e:
    374                         self.classifier = pysol.SOL('rda', num_class, **self.params)
--> 375                         train_accuracy = self.classifier.fit(X, Y_new)
    376                         return train_accuracy
    377 

python/pysol.pyx in python.pysol.SOL.fit (python/pysol.cpp:4250)()

python/pysol.pyx in python.pysol.SOL.__load_data (python/pysol.cpp:3777)()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

what should i do to normalize my list so that i can train my machine learning? I'm using python 2.7

Comment: You will need to show the traceback where you get the error too. There's nothing referring to `dtype` here.

Comment: You need a 2-dimensional array rather than a list of 1-dimensional arrays. I.e. (if you are using numpy), ```list_train = np.array(list_train)```

Comment: @AKX, I already add the traceback error.

Comment: @tofd the problem is i have no idea how to remove 'array' and concatenate all of array inside the list.

Comment: @azizahn add ```list_train = np.array(list_train)``` and ```list_test = np.array(list_test)```  above the line ```finalpred = clf3.fit(list_train, y_train)``` and try again. If you haven't already, you need to import numpy ```import numpy as np```